# CSS not working in Chrome and not in firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

CSS not working in Chrome and not in firefox

Original CSS

```
background: url("../images/shortcut-button-bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left top #F7F7F7;
border: 1px solid green;
display: -moz-inline-stack;
margin: 0 0 20px;
width: 201px;
```

Firefox FireBug Show it as

```
 background: url("../images/shortcut-button-bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left top #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    width: 201px;
```

and in Chrome Firebug

```
 background: url("../images/shortcut-button-bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left top #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    width: 140px;
```

Please Reply me and told me Browser Compatibilty using CSS

Comment: Chrome has no "Firebug" but its own "Developer Tools".

Comment: @feeela there is a "Firebug" for chrome....http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: @Pabloker Oh – OK. Now I can use the slowest code inspector of all in any browser ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When you use a vendor specific prefix like `display: -moz-inline-stack;`, it targets a particular browser. Here, as you might have guessed by the **-moz** prefix, it is understood only by firefox. That might be why this is happening.

Try a cross-browser solution like this **[one](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)**.

The things you might need to add are:

```
    display: -moz-inline-stack; //for firefox
    display: inline-block; //for other browsers
    *display: inline;  //for IE6 & 7
    zoom: 1; //for IE6 & 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer, but Chrome doesn't know `display: -moz-inline-stack;`. Also use `display: inline-block;` right under `display: -moz-inline-stack;`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself, but Chrome and Firefox show both width:201px;
The 140px should be defined somewhere in your style.

Answer (score 0):

Try losing the -moz- bit from the style declarations. Most modern browsers should not need them nowadays with HTML5 coming along. Possible CSS display values are :-

```
    none    The element will not be displayed at all
    block   The element is displayed as a block element (like paragraphs and headers). A block element has some whitespace above and below it and does not tolerate any HTML elements next to it
    inline  This is default. The element is displayed as an inline element (like span). An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it tolerates HTML elements next to it
    inline-block    The element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element
    inline-table    The element is displayed as an inline table
    list-item   The element is displayed as a list-item, which means that it has a bullet in front of it
    table   The element is displayed as a table
    table-caption   The element is displayed as a table caption
    table-cell  The element is displayed as a table cell
    table-column    The element is displayed as a table column
    table-column-group  The element is displayed as a table column group (like <colgroup>)
    table-footer-group  The element is displayed as a table footer row group
    table-header-group  The element is displayed as a table header row group
    table-row   The element is displayed as a table row
    table-row-group     The element is displayed as a table row group
    inherit     The value of the display property will be inherited from the parent element
```

Since there is no "inline-stack" value, you should use "inline", or drop the "display" item completely. It should read :-

```
    display: inline;
```